# Доступ к защищенному внутреннему классу предка из класса-наследника

Tags: java, наследование, inner, protected

В трех разных пакетах размещены:

- интерфейс (MyInterfaceInner);
- класс предок (GeneralClass), имеющий защищенный внутренний класс (ProtectedClass);
- класс наследник (DerivativeClass).

Не могу в классе наследника написать метод, возвращающий ссылку на объект внутреннего класса предка. Идея предлагает сделать класс ProtectedClass `public`, в этом случае все работает.
Т.к. модификатор `protected` распространяет свой доступ и на наследников (а это вроде мой случай), то удивляет то, что код не компилируется. Кто-нибудь может пояснить в чем дело?

```
public interface MyInterfaceInner {
    void print();
}


public class GeneralClass {

    protected class ProtectedClass implements MyInterfaceInner {

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Как здорово, что все мы здесь сегодня собрались");
        }
    }
}


public class DerivativeClass extends GeneralClass {

    public ProtectedClass getProtectedClass() {
        GeneralClass g = new GeneralClass();
        // в этой строке код не компилируется
        GeneralClass.ProtectedClass p = g.new ProtectedClass();
        return p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего следует отметить, что указанная проблема не воспроизводится для кода, *представленного в вопросе*, так как в нём все классы находятся в одном и том же пакете по умолчанию.

Поэтому код, приведённый в вопросе, должен был непосредственно указывать, что все классы находятся в *отдельных* пакетах.

Фактически проблема, описанная в вопросе, связана с тем, что неявные конструкторы *по умолчанию* имеют тот же спецификатор доступа, что и класс, в котором они описаны, то есть, у класса `ProtectedClass` его неявный конструктор по умолчанию также является `protected`.

То есть, доступ к такому конструктору возможен только из класса, который:

- принадлежит к тому же пакету, что и класс `GeneralClass.ProtectedClass`
- является подклассом класса `GeneralClass.ProtectedClass`
  что не выполняется для класса `DerivativeClass`, который наследует *только внешний класс `GeneralClass`*.

Поэтому следует либо обеспечить доступ как минимум к конструктору класса `GeneralClass.ProtectedClass`, сделав его открытым:

```java
public class GeneralClass {

    protected class ProtectedClass implements MyInterfaceInner {
        public ProtectedClass() {} // нужен открытый доступ

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("ProtectedClass");
        }
    }
}
```

*Разумеется, если бы у класса `ProtectedClass` (и соответственно его конструктора по умолчанию) был открытый доступ, указанной проблемы не возникло бы.*

Либо следует в классе `DerivativeClass` дополнительно создать внутренний класс -- потомок класса `ProtectedClass` и возвращать соответственно его экземпляр:

```java
public class DerivativeClass extends GeneralClass {

    protected class DerivedProtectedClass extends ProtectedClass {

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("derived protected");
        }
    }

    public ProtectedClass getProtectedClass() {
        // всё работает!
        GeneralClass.ProtectedClass p = new DerivativeClass().new DerivedProtectedClass();
        return p;
    }
}
```

---

Аналогичный вопрос на основном SO: [Protected nested class not accessible to derived classes in other package (2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605388/)